# htaccess remove folder from url only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im trying to remove only a specific folder from my url. i have see many answers here but i cant find any to work for me.
i have this url http://www.mydomain.com/projects/books/index.php
i want to just remove the projects folder so i can use 
http://www.mydomain.com/books/index.php

i have this .htacces inside public_html folder :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)projects 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/$1 [L]
```

with this code i can access http://www.mydomain.com/books/index.php but any other address redirect me inside the projcets folder 
for example http://www.mydomain.com shows me the index of/ projects
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(projects/|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /projects/$1 [L]
```

Comment: this is working somehow but the css and js are not loading in the first page

Comment: Fr css/js just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
OR else you can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: in another site with the same projects folder i get this error: The requested URL /projects/index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: almost.it doesnt have an index.php inside, only other php's like test.php

Comment: Then 404 is expected on other site isn't it?

Comment: true,but i dont whant to have an index.php inside that folder

Comment: thank you for the help, still not working.now i dont get 404 but it adds /projects/ in all paths, for example i have a css in my php and i call it like that:<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mysite.com/css/style.css" media="all" /> if i try to access it http://www.mysite.com/css/style.css i get The requested URL /projects/css/style.css was not found on this server.